# Extract integer in a filename from complete path using split regex in Pandas

Tags: python, regex, pandas, split

Given a `df`

```
df=pd.DataFrame(['/home/dtest/Documents/user/exp/S1/test1/test3/sub5/file_2_F__131147.png',
                 '/home/dtest/Documents/user/exp/S1/test1/test3/sub5/file_2_F__160565.png'])
```

I would like to extract only the integer just before the file extension.

The code below should answer the above objective

```
df['fname'] =df[0].apply(lambda x : os.path.split(x)[1])
df['f'] =df['fname'].apply(lambda x : x.split('__')[1].split('.png')[0])
df['f']=df['f'].astype(int)
```

However, I have the impression this can be achieve easily using pandas build-in `split`, such as below

```
df['f']=df[0].str.split(re.compile(r"__\d.jpg"), expand=True)
```

But, it seems nothing is being split. May I know what parameter not being set correctly?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Series.str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html):

```py
df['num'] = df['f'].str.extract(r'_(\d+)\.[^.]+$', expand=False)
```

[**Test your regexes here**](https://regex101.com/r/ApH07E/1).

**Details**:

- `_` - an underscore
- `(\d+)` - Capturing group 1 (this is the value returned by `Series.str.extract`): one or more digits
- `\.` - a `.` char
- `[^.]+` - one or more chars other than a `.` char
- `$` - end of string

Python test:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'f':['/home/dtest/Documents/user/exp/S1/test1/test3/sub5/file_2_F__131147.png',
    '/home/dtest/Documents/user/exp/S1/test1/test3/sub5/file_2_F__160565.png']})
df['num'] = df['f'].str.extract(r'_(\d+)\.[^.]+$', expand=False)
print(df.to_string())
```

Output:

```
                                                                         f     num
0  /home/dtest/Documents/user/exp/S1/test1/test3/sub5/file_2_F__131147.png  131147
1  /home/dtest/Documents/user/exp/S1/test1/test3/sub5/file_2_F__160565.png  160565
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `0` the name of your column (as in your example), you can use [`str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html):

```
df[0].str.extract(r'(\d+)\.[^.]+$', expand=False)
```

output:

```
0    131147
1    160565
Name: 0, dtype: object
```

To assign to a new column:

```
df['f'] = df[0].str.extract(r'(\d+)\.[^.]+$')
```

[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/6YzBKX/1)

Answer (score 0):

```
def extract(values):
    values = values.split('__') # cut at '__'
    return int(values[-1].replace('.png','')) # take the last part en replace the .png

df[0].apply(extract)
```